# Count values in a range that are less than a certain number AND present in another range

Tags: google-sheets-formula

END GOAL:
I have two ranges, and I need to know how many items are found in each range AND are less than 5.

So if range 1 is:

```
3
4
5
6
7
```

and range 2 is

```
1
3
4
7
```

then I'd get an answer of

```
2
```

since only 3 and 4 are less than 5 AND in both ranges.

I'm using this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B5:B11,D5:D11))
```

And it works well to tell me how many matches in one range are present in another, but I want to limit by adding a second conditional: they need to match AND be less than 5.

Comment: Microsoft Excel is not Google Sheets. Which of the two are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out! The solution was as simple as:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B5:B11,D5:D11,B5:B11,"<5"))
```